# How can I insert a UISegmentedControl to a navigationBar using RubyMotion?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol, rubymotion

I've built an iOS application using Xcode which I'm now transposing over to RubyMotion.

Using interface builder I was able to add a segmented control to my navigation bar on one of my view controllers. When I try to recreate this programatically in RubyMotion the app crashes without reporting what the error was.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?
Also, is init the best place to declare this? Or one of the view lifecycle callbacks such as viewDidLoad?

```
class MyController < UIViewController

  def init
    if super
      image = UIImage.imageNamed('tab_bar_icons/one.png')
      self.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.alloc.initWithTitle('One', image: image, tag:1)
      self.navigationItem.titleView = searchTypeContol # when commented out, the app doesn't crash!
    end
    self
  end

  def searchTypeControl
    @searchTypeControl ||= begin
      _searchTypeControl = UISegmentedControl.alloc.initWithFrame( CGRectZero)
      _searchTypeControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar
      _searchTypeControl.insertSegmentWithTitle('One', atIndex: 0, animated: false)
      _searchTypeControl.insertSegmentWithTitle('Two', atIndex: 0, animated: false)
      _searchTypeControl.insertSegmentWithTitle('Three', atIndex: 0, animated: false)
      _searchTypeControl.sizeToFit
      _searchTypeControl
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo... :/

Line #7 should be `searchTypeControl` not `searchTypeContol`

I wish RubyMotion had reported this back to me :(